# How do I go from existence of inductive sets to the existence of infinite sets?

Tags: set-theory

I saw this problem in the exercises of Set Theory by Jech at the end of Chapter 2 (it's problem 2.4 in the book). So the proof doesn't need to involve notions of cardinality.

The problem talks about a case where the axiom of infinity doesn't exist. How do I go from the existence of an inductive set to the existence of an infinite set? Infinite set is defined as a set that doesn't have a one-to-one mapping onto some $n \in \boldsymbol{N}$.

Comment: Prove it by contradiction, assume an inductive set was in bijection to $n$, then show you can make it one bigger

Comment: Pigeonhole principle.